# camera result decrease over the period of time

Tags: android, camera, mobile-phone

I am using moto g 1st generation Android mobile from Motorola, when i have purchased it in 2014, Its camera result was soo good...But after almost 2 years when i take any photos and compare it with my old photos taken with same camera then i feel that camera's performance is degraded.

Same thing was observed by my some friends with Samsung's android smart phone. So just wanted to know the reason behind this thing.

1) Is it any kind of camera sensors's limitation/issue. So after taking X number of photos its performance will be degraded as such?

2) Due to any kind of dust gathered near camers glass i feel that?

3) Or Vendor released smart phone with some 3rd party image processing algorithm which licence was just for 2 years or some time and after that time it stop working. SO i feel bad result with my smart phone camera

4) Technologies keep upgraded so i feel that, like in 2014 we had usually
5 Megapixcel camera and now we have 16 Megapixcel camera in smart phones so i feel that...

6) Have you observed such things with your smart phone or any other camera?

Comment: Did you **read** the Android tag you included?
You are asking an off-topic question. Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic, except insofar as they interface with your computer, See [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, try cleaning the lens, that worked for me

Comment: Dirty or scratched lens cover is the most likely cause of this.